# c++ memory leak with structures?

Tags: pointers

Let's say I allocate memory to a pointer to a structure:

```
CatStructure * cat; // assume a CatStructure has name and weight
```

Let's say I initialize cat to:

```
cat->name = "pippy";
cat->weight = 100;
```

If I save a reference to cat->name and cat->weight, do I still need to save a reference to cat? In other words, is it necessary to save a reference to a pointer to a structure **if** I've already saved references to its members?

Comment: Are you asking whether you can get a pointer to `cat` by `cat->name` and `cat->weight?`.

Comment: @delnan, I don't think so. I was just curious if it's acceptable to save a reference to a pointer to a structure's members and not the actual pointer to structure. I think Donnie answered my question - "No."

Answer (score 1):

`CatStructure *cat;` does not allocate memory for the given struct, it just gives you a place to store a reference to a pointer.  We'll say that you know this, and that you're `new`ing correctly to actually allocate memory.

Every `new` must be matched with a corresponding call to `delete` or you *will* leak memory.  Technically if you're saving a reference to one of the members correctly you could do some pointer math to recover the reference to the struct, but that's unnecessarily obtuse.  Just save the pointer so you can clean it up later.

Comment: Clever pointer math to avoid keeping proper references around break garbage collection (if you have it) and certainly make leak detectors complain a lot.

Answer (score 0):

if you delete the structure, any references to its pointers or members will no longer be valid. those invalid pointers/references are called 'dangling'.